# curl php загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь загрузить файл excel в одно веб-приложение
делаю так (никаких ошибок не возвращает, но в ответ и не приходит массив который должен прийти):

```
$this->headers = [
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
        "Referer: http://domain.com/hand.html",
        "Origin: http://domain.com",
        "UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
      ];

      $post = [
        "file" => curl_file_create ("../../test.xlsx"), "name" => "test.xlsx",
        "name" => "test.xlsx"
      ];

      $this->curl = curl_init ($url);
      curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
      curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
      $result = curl_exec ($this->curl);
      curl_close ($this->curl);
      $json = json_decode ($result, true);
      return $json;
```

Comment: ......exec......
if (!curl_errno($this->curl)) {
  $info = curl_getinfo($this->curl);
  print_r($info);
}

Comment: ошибка 26 - CURLE_READ_ERROR

Comment: There was a problem reading a local file or an error returned by the read callback
Скорее всего файл который вы отправляете - недоступен - 
print_r(is_file ()) сделайте

Comment: обернул путь в realpath, теперь ошибка CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL (is_file === true)

Comment: is_file показал true ?

Comment: в общем, сейчас curl_errno - возвращает 0... но результат все равно не приходит от сервера

Comment: curl_getinfo что возвращает?

Comment: Разобрался, сейчас ответ приходит, но в массиве записана ошибка... И файл как то подозрительно долго загружается... Если вручную загружаю то моментально, а если программой то минуты 3 жду... Заметил если ставить content-size очень маленький то тоже быстро проходит... Однако тоже с ошибкой... Либо с заголовками что то не то, либо с массивом который я отправляю

Comment: Проверил на своем localhost - такая же фигня... загрузка идет долго, массив POST приходит пустой, а в массиве FILES - ошибка 3 (файл получен частично)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все) разобрался с этим...
1 - проверить корректно ли указан путь к файлу как сказал sterx, через is_file
2 - путь нужно было обернуть дополнительно в realpath
3 - убрать заголовок Content-Length: $size, т.к. убрав его все загрузилось нормально и быстро... Поставил я его потому что читал одну из статей где было указано, что этот заголовок обязательно нужно передавать... Странно, ну да ладно)